# How to rewrite custom module url including id with any custom url in Magento

Tags: php, url-rewriting, magento-1.9, custom-url

I have installed storelocator in Magento that is free extension.But if it is clicked on `View Details` button, it is opened with **storelocator/index/view/id/1/**. For SEO purpose, it is needed to open with **hearing-aid-center-in-new-york** or **hearing-aid-center-in-Chicago**. here it will be common with **hearing-aid-center-in-** and **new-york, chikago** will be coming dynamic. So, for this requirement, how to rewrite this url. And Where I should write the rewrite the code for the above requirement. I had tried a lot with id 1 as static way by creating observer using Magento event "controller_front_init_routers" by the help of this site https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73369/custom-url-for-magento-extension. It is saved in core_url_rewrite and it it shows in "URL Rewrite Management" section and it also redirects, but redirects 404 Not Found page.I can't understand why it redirects 404 Not Found page and how to implement it and how to get id of storelocator in overserver dynamic way.

Besides it, I also need to override the customer account url and sales order history url.
I don't know how to rewrite the customer account url with **/my-account/order-history** instead of **/sales/order/history/** and also with **/my-account/dashboard** instead of **/customer/account/**.I can't understand how to implement these requirement for friendly SEO purpose. Any help, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend Store locator with a new module that depends on it. There are loads of posts out there on how to do this. This module will need to add an additional attribute for URL Key e.g. new-york. It would also need a new Controller that extends `Storelocator_IndexController`. This controller will handle all requests for Stores. It will lookup for the Store by URL Key instead of ID. Once it has this it will continue using the inherit code as before. Of course you will have to override and update all Urls to use the Key.

Lastly you would need a rewrite rule in the `config.xml` like:

`<config>
    <global>
        <rewrite>
            <mymodule_storelocatoroverides_view>
                <from><![CDATA[#^\/hearing\-aid\-center\-in\-([a-z\-]+)[\/]?$#]]></from>
                <to><![CDATA[mymodule/storelocatoroverides/view/id/1/]]></to>
                <complete>1</complete>
            </mymodule_storelocatoroverides_view>
        </rewrite>
    </global>
</config>`

**Alternatively**

As a quick solution but by no means the best solution:

If you have a finite number of stores, then you can simple add rewrite rules in a module config.xml (create a simple plugin) E.g for New York (assuming its ID 1):

`<config>
    <global>
        <rewrite>
            <mymodule_storelocatoroverides_newyork>
                <from><![CDATA[#^\/hearing\-aid\-center\-in\-new\-york[\/]?$#]]></from>
                <to><![CDATA[storelocator/index/view/id/1/]]></to>
                <complete>1</complete>
            </mymodule_storelocatoroverides_newyork>
        </rewrite>
    </global>
</config>`

Again you would have to override the Url outputs.

As for the Customer Url's you can use the same approach again. So add Rewrites to the `config.xml` and replace Url links to use your new rewrites. Again you may have to override Core code to change the redirects.

Hope that helps!